Why does systemd create so many tmpfs files? And how to disable them?
I have installed and updated Debian testing yesterday,
and now I see several files on tmpfs:
df -h
Sist. Arq.      Tam. Usado Disp. Uso% Montado em
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           128M  4,4M  124M   4% /run
/dev/sdc2       456G  149G  285G  35% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  8,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs        192K   34K  154K  19% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-journald.service
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-udev-load-credentials.service
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-sysctl.service
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
/dev/nvme0n1    233G   20G  214G   9% /mnt/some
/dev/sdd2        92G  1,8G   91G   2% /mnt/some2
/dev/sde        3,7T  1,3T  2,4T  35% /mnt/some3
/dev/sda        2,8T  703G  2,1T  26% /mnt/some4
/dev/sdb         17T  1,4T   16T   9% /mnt/some5
/dev/sdc1       511M  4,4M  507M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
tmpfs           1,0M     0  1,0M   0% /run/credentials/getty@tty1.service
tmpfs           3,2G   28K  3,2G   1% /run/user/0`

I already mount /run on a tmpfs using fstab:
# <file system>      <mount point>      <type>      <options>               <dump>  <pass>
tmpfs                /run               tmpfs       defaults,size=128M      0       0

My question is: WHY systemd insists on creating another tmpfs and consuming RAM? 
I already mount a /run on a tmpfs! 
Why need to mount these /run/credentials mountpoints? 
On this specific device, I have 32 GB of RAM,
but I have some other old devices that have 512 MB of memory. 
And, if possible, a way to disable these auto tmpfs filesystem creations on systemd (/run/credentials/*, especially except /run/user/someone systemd-pam that I already disabled and system have some fails because of that).

@ArtemS.Tashkinov it's not ranting, it's a legitimate question.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov "rant" implies rudeness and aggression. The OP is being perfectly calm and civil, calling this a rant is completely out of line. You could simply explain and post an answer instead of throwing names around. There is no expression of opinion either for or against systemd in this post as far as I can tell, just a question about it and how it works.

How much RAM is consumed by those filesystems? Your df output shows that they're all empty.

As I sayed, these server is an example. In other systems that I won't have great amount of RAM I have problem with these approach. Friends, my objective is only discover how to disable these feature and back to old style. If won't have any way to do these I will find another way. Thanks for your help.

The question remains: How much RAM is consumed by those filesystems? On any normal system, the total memory in use by all those tmpfs instances should be below 10-20 MB. If you have any tmpfs instances that have more than 50+ MB, then your objective should be to 1) figure out how that amount of data ended up there and 2) maybe disable that specific tmpfs instance – not literally all of them.
